# parsing NSData object for information

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdata

I have a `NSData` object coming back from my server, it varies in its content but sticks to a particular structure.

I would like to know (hopfully with some example code) how to work though this object to get the data I need out of it.

the structure of the data objects inside the objects are like this

- leading value (*UInt16*) - (tells me what section of the response it is)
- Size of string (*UInt32*) **or** number - (*UInt32*)
- String (not null terminated) i.e. followed by the next leading value.

I have been reading through the [Binary Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingBinaryData.html) however that's only really showing me how to put my data into new `NSData` objects and accessing and compairing the bytes.

The thing I am stuck on is how do I say grab the info dynamically. Check the `NSdata` objects first leading value figure out if its string or int then get the string or int and move onto the next leading value..

any suggestions or example code would be really helpfull.. just stuck in abit of a mind block as I have never attempted anything like this in objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of this depends on how your server is written to encode the data into what it is sending you. Assuming it is encoding the numeric values using standard network byte ordering (big-endian) you will want it converted to the correct byte-ordering for iOS (I believe that is always little-endian).

I would approach it something like this:

```
uint16_t typeWithNetworkOrdering, typeWithLocalOrdering;
uint32_t sizeWithNetworkOrdering, sizeWithLocalOrdering;
char *cstring = NULL;
uint32_t numberWithNetworkOrdering, numberWithLocalOrdering;
const void *bytes = [myData bytes];
NSUInteger length = [myData length];

while (length > 0) {
    memcpy(&typeWithNetworkOrdering, bytes, sizeof(uint16_t));
    bytes += sizeof(uint16_t);
    length -= sizeof(uint16_t);
    memcpy(&sizeWithNetworkOrdering, bytes, sizeof(uint32_t));
    bytes += sizeof(uint32_t);
    length -= sizeof(uint32_t);
    typeWithLocalOrdering = CFSwapInt16BigToHost(typeWithNetworkOrdering);
    sizeWithLocalOrdering = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(sizeWithNetworkOrdering);

    if (typeWithLocalOrdering == STRING_TYPE) { // STRING_TYPE is whatever type value corresponds to a string
        cstring = (char *) malloc(sizeWithLocalOrdering + 1);
        strncpy(cstring, bytes, sizeWithLocalOrdering);
        cstring[sizeWithLocalOrdering] = '\0';
        NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithCString:cstring encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"String = %@", resultString);
        free(cstring);
        bytes += sizeWithLocalOrdering;
        length -= sizeWithLocalOrdering;
        // Do whatever you need to with the string
    }
    else if (typeWithLocalOrdering == NUMBER_TYPE) { // NUMBER_TYPE is whatever type value corresponds to a number
        memcpy(&numberWithNetworkOrdering, bytes, sizeof(uint32_t));
        numberWithLocalOrdering = CFSwapInt32BigToHost(numberWithNetworkOrdering);
        NSLog(@"Number = %u", numberWithLocalOrdering);
        bytes += sizeof(uint32_t);
        length -= sizeof(uint32_t);
        // Do whatever you need to with the number
    }
}
```

Comment: okay cool, reading this though now :) yes the byte order is big-endian.. reading now.. thanks for the answer.

Comment: I keep getting a warning where I am passing my data to bytes **void *bytes = [myData bytes];** the warning is saying **initalizing 'void *' with an expression of type 'const void*' discards qualifiers* I have looked around for what this means but dont really understand any of the responses i have see for them so far.

Comment: That's what I get for typing in a response without compiling it myself to check ;) I just put it into Xcode to compile and corrected that along with a couple other typos. (Added "@" before strings in the NSLog's, corrected a copy/paste error initializing length, and corrected the NSLog showing the number value)

Comment: okay cool, going to go over it now.. all good though because i did lots of reading on some of the functions and am learning lots of cool things.

Comment: I hate doing this to people but I think I am going to have to change the tick.. this post has helped me alot and I feel more secure knowing I am handling things how I am supposed too.. Thanks heaps Tim :)

Comment: So I think there might be an Inherent flaw in my question. I did not clarify that the data I have coming back is in HEX format. i.e. the leading values that are of type UInt_16 come back like so 01 00 (big endian).. then length identifier being UInt_32 07 00 00 00 (also big endian).. I am guessing I will have to convert the data to a byte array first or something.. I'm not to sure, if you are able to advise me on how to handle that it would really help. again thanks for all the help so far :)

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to say that these numbers come back in the HEX format. To say that a leading value comes back as 01 00 here is to say that it is a byte valued at 1 followed by a byte valued at 0, which equates to a numeric value of 1 under a big-endian byte order. "00" and "01" are only how those numbers are displayed in a string. The only way to actually have the values come back in hex is if the hex representation 4-character string "0100" were in your data, but putting those 4 characters in your data would actually take at least 4 bytes (which wouldn't fit into a uint32.

Comment: So in other words, I don't think it is possible for you data to come in "in HEX format" and simultaneously take up only 2 bytes for the leading value as you say. So if you have some aspect of this that is not working, please post the specific problem. "It is using Hex format" is not your problem, unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8373/discussion-between-tim-dean-and-c-johns)

Comment: sorry to bother you again tim, I have been working though your code and its doing something funny with the NSString *resultString, when I log it to the console it comes back with different things like OnlinepƄ or Onlinen or Onlinepڧ etc.. but I cannot seem to figure out why. I think its because its accessing things it shouldnt be but when I check the length of sizeWithLocalOrdering its correct... for instance it says 6 for Online etc.. just abit confused.

Comment: Looks like the C string that gets converted to an NSString is not being nil-terminated, I added an explicit line to terminate cstring after it is set with strncpy. I would have thought it would have done that implicitly but I might be off on that. Try the update to see if that works.

Comment: ha! thanks tim, trying now.. I was looking at the memcpy function thinking it might be something happening between then and when it gets passed to the nsstring.. but I had no idea how to test for it... trying updated code now... Tested!!! Worked perfectly! thanks very much!

Comment: sorry tim, One last question with regards to the second if statment. The format of a number is only Uint16 value and Uint32 (which if its a string is used as the length identifier, but if its a number then its just the actual number so its value, number.. then the next section value... etc) so in the if statement I have removed bytes += sizeof(uint32_t); length -= sizeof(uint32_t); and Im accessing each section properly however the number dose not log correctly. when its supposed to be 1 it is 8454147 :(

Comment: If you're still stuck then let's move the discussion back to chat -

Comment: Figured it out Tim sorry for the delay in reply, was the weekend etc. But yea figured out that I did't need bytes += sizeWithLocalOrdering;
            length -= sizeWithLocalOrdering; inside an if that was for an integer as it was only (value)(int) where as strings are (value)(int/length of)(string) so yea.. all sorted! got my whole stream comming in and being decoded which is super cool :) thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Define your own internal structs and cast the pointer to it:

```
NSData* data;
struct headerType
{
    uint16_t type;
    uint32_t length;

};
const struct headerType* header=(const struct headerType*)[data bytes]; // get the header of the response
if (header->type==1)
{
    const char* text=((const char*)header)+6; // skip the header (16bits+32bits=6 bytes offset)
}
```

EDIT:
If you need to read them in a loop:

```
NSData* data;
const uint8_t* cursor=(const uint8_t*)[data bytes];
while (true)
{
    uint16_t type=*((uint16_t*)cursor);
    cursor+=2;
    if (cursor==1)
    {
        // string
        uint32_t length=*((uint32_t*)cursor);
        cursor+=4;
        const char* str=(const char*)cursor;
        cursor+=length;
    }
    else if (cursor==2)
    {
        // another type
    }
    else
        break;
}
```

Comment: okay, choice.. I get this, however for my headerType I think I might just get the uint16_1 type only then create different if statments for each of the sections that way if one is a string i add the uint32_t length then read the bytes from there.. or if its a number i can just get the number.. it makes sense... also I can build in checking from there. The only question I have is that, if i dont no where the next type is how can I check for it.. would I say return a value from my if statments saying finished this section check next section?

Comment: also, if the data now represents the type as a hex number.. what would I check for here **if (header->type==1)**

Comment: i've edited my answer to show how to read the response in a loop.

Comment: I strongly suspect that this will not work well, and even if it did you want to avoid it. First of all, byte ordering for integers make things more complicated when you have numeric types. Second of all, you don't want to assume that a structure like headerType in this response will align all its members to byte boundaries that match what is in your NSData object.

Comment: I'm with @TimDean. Won't the compiler align the UInt32 to a word boundary? That would mean 2 bytes of padding between type and length in the struct, breaking the format.

Comment: I also prefer to avoid using binary data between client and server. I usually prefer JSON for that, but I was just trying to show how to access binary data. There are a lot of things to consider when doing that (byte ordering is only one of them, not to mention security as well).

Comment: ah crap.. this is turning out alot harder than I was hoping.. I don't have a good enough command over data types.. I have read so much but still feels like I might be missing things

Comment: @joerick you can always use #pragma pack to align them to 1 byte

Comment: @C.Johns why not use JSON? it is strongly typed and is supported well on both iOS and PHP

Comment: @Gilad when you refer to security do you mean people being able to access the data in some way? I am communicating with the data base via https

Comment: @Gilad, it was the choice of the db engine developer. the communication layer is going to be able to deal this data out over to all sorts of different devices / computers. I guess it makes it easier else where where as for the on ios its making things alot more difficult.

Comment: https is only one layer, but another potential problem would be if later on you extend your structure (on the server) - leaving some users with old clients. They might read some data they can't parse. In a good scenario - the app will just crash. In the worst case it might lead to buffer overrun. When dealing with server, unless speed is extremely important (RT gaming for example), you should prefer an extendable protocol (XML/JSON), I personally prefer JSON.

Comment: @C.Johns I see. If you don't have a choice, then start with the example I've showed you. As Tim pointed out, you should consider the byte ordering (you can use ntohl or similar to convert them). Eventually, you'll still have to cast the data to a simple pointer and advance on it based on your data model.

Comment: ahh right. Yea, I'm kind of in a situation where I have been working with objective C for about a year right out of uni, and the guy developing the communication layers and db engine has been developing for the past 30 years. So its pretty hard to talk with him about things because I don't understand ios well enough..

Comment: I've been developing for 30 years as well and I still use JSON on servers :)

Comment: okay, thanks alot for helping me out and thanks to the rest of you for identifying the problems I am facing.. this is all helping me learn more and more :) cheers guys.

Comment: The apple documentation under "Encoding and Decoding C Data Types" states quite clearly that you shouldn't make alignment assumptions like this when mapping between NSData bytes and structures. I'm voting down this answer because it seems like a very bad approach to solving the problem.