# How do I determine if an NSData object contains a specific HTML tag?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [parsing NSData object for information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507053/parsing-nsdata-object-for-information)

I have a NSData object. I want to see whether it contains an HTML tag or not. How can I parse the NSData object to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

Parse the bytes and look for bytes that represent HTML tags.

Comment: Is this the correct way of doing it:  NSString *aResults = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:iInputObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];  if (aResults && [aResults containsString:@"<html>"]) { // Do Something }